# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The media set has 2 media families but only 1 are provided. All members must be provided. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Tags: 2013, administration, sql-server, restore, database

I want to Backup/Restore our managed metadata managed service's database from live to test which are both sharepoint 2013 farms. So i did these steps:-

1- Inside the live database i select the related managed metadata database >> right click on it >> Tasks >> Back Up... >> and i got a file named `ttd.bak` of size 1.9 MB, as follow:-
[image]

2- then inside our test database , i created a new database with the same name as the live >> right click on the "Databases" >> click on "Restore Database" >> i select the new database and the `ttd.back`, but i got this error:-

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Restore failed for Server 'WIN-SPDEV'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.4000.0+((KJ_PCU_Main).120628-0827+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Restore+Server&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The media set has 2 media families but only 1 are provided. All members must be provided. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.4000.0+((KJ_PCU_Main).120628-0827+)&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

as follow:-
[image]

so can anyone advice on this? now our live environment (which i backup-ed the DB from) has the SP database on separate VM, while our test server (where i am trying to restore the DB) has the database server inside the same VM as sharepoint.. not sure if this is related to my problem?

Answer (score 2):

this is becuase of the way you are performing the backups of your db.

1. When you make the backup, change the Backup Set Name.
2. Remove all of the destinations listed, and add 1 new destination.
3. Do a full backup.
4. Restore this back file .
   [Source](https://ask-dotnet.blogspot.com/2013/02/systemdatasqlclientsqlerror-media-set.html)

Also the answer here to understand it.https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/abf50e00-c9b0-4809-9e61-43ed8a53e968/the-media-set-has-2-media-families-but-only-1-are-provided

Comment: i did not get your points...can you please explain the cause and the solution?

Comment: now i repeated the backup again, and i got a file which is almost double the size of the previous file and when i restore it , it worked well, so i am not sure what is going on!!

Comment: Maybe you originally were splitting backup into 2 separate files?

Comment: @Marek Sarad  Thanks for the reply... i do not think i have specified to split it into 2 separate files... can you advice how an export inside the sql management studio can be defined to split the backup file into 2 separate files? and why would a backup task cause the backup file to be splitting into 2 file,, i do not think this was the case..